# Como comparo datos de una tabla SQL y obtener la diferencia

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que me pueda ayudar en obtener ese **resultado**, estoy trabajando en **SQL Server**

Tengo al momento esta consulta

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.cantidad, T2.cantidad
                FROM tabla T1
                LEFT JOIN tabla T2
                    ON  T1.ID = T2.ID
               WHERE T1.otroid= 1922 AND T2.otroid=2014 UNION SELECT T1.ID, T1.cantidad, T2.cantidad
                        FROM tabla T2
                        LEFT JOIN tabla T1
                            ON  T1.ID = T2.ID
                    WHERE T1.otrocampoid= 1922 AND T2.otrocampoid=2014
```

pero igual no me trae el campo que existe en una y no en la otra.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! intentaste algo? eso se hace con un join

Comment: Piensa en la teoría de conjuntos: A y B son tus tablas.  Según tu gráfica hay que hacer una nueva tabla que SUME los resultados de: A menos B, y luego B menos A

Comment: Para la proxima, aclara en que base de datos estas trabajando...

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el resultado combinado debes hacer:

1. Un `join` de las tablas por los campos clave `id`.
2. Este join debe permitir, segun el resultado que muestas, obtener el campo `cantidad` de ambas tablas independientemente que uno tenga o no data, por lo tanto vamos hacer un `full join` o `full outer join`.
3. Los campos `cantidad` deben ponerse como parametros de funciones de agregacion `sum` ya que tendrias que agrupar por estos campos.
4. Por ultimo, agrupamos por los campos Id.

A continuacion el `select` para obtener el resultado que muestas en la imagen:

```
select isnull(a.Id, b.Id), sum(a.cantidad) as cantTabla1, sum(b.cantidad) as cantTabla2,
       sum(abs(isnull(a.cantidad, 0) - isnull(b.cantidad, 0))) as dif 
from Tabla1 a full join Tabla2 b on a.Id = b.Id
group by a.Id, b.Id
```

Comment: @BetaM De acuerdo... lo editare.

Comment: Ademas en general tratamos de no contestar preguntas que no tengan un intento de solucion del problema...

Comment: y ademas.. esto no funciona.. no muestra los id de b en la solucion...

Comment: Esta bien por obtener la diferencia, pero entonces no esta mostrando los ID que están en una tabla y no en la otra.

Comment: @gbianchi tengo hasta el momento esto pero igual no me trae la informacion que esta en una tabla y no en la otra. 
    `SELECT T1.ID, T1.cantidad,T2.cantidad  FROM tabla T1  LEFT JOIN tabla T2                        ON  T1.ID = T2.ID   WHERE T1.ID= 12999 AND T2.ID=12775 UNION SELECT T1.ID, T1.cantidad, T2.cantidad   FROM tabla T2                            LEFT JOIN tabla T1    ON  T1.ID = T2.ID     WHERE T1.ID= 12775 AND T2.ID=12999 `

Comment: @luc0187 eso debe ir en tu pregunta, y explicar porque pensas que eso remotamente soluciona tu problema.. porque por lo que veo ese query no tiene nada que ver con lo que queres solucionar...